# How to use the socket select function

Tags: sockets, select

I'm trying to understand the socket `select` function.

The first argument, I've read that `nfds` can be ignored, should be one more the highest descriptor value and also that it should be max count + 1.

What should that number be?

Also if I've got select fds added via FD_SET(), when select returns...

what's the way to iterate thru all the fds that are set (e.g. readable)

with doing something like

```
if ( FD_SET(socket1, &fds) )
 ...
if ( FD_SET(socket2, &fds) )
  ...
```

I suppose I could put them in an array - but i was hoping there would be an iterator function.

Answer (score 2):

> I've read that `nfds` can be ignored

Only for WinSock's `select()` on Windows.  For `select()` on other platforms, `nfds` is required.

> The first argument ... should be one more the highest descriptor value and also that it should be max count + 1.
>
> What should that number be?

Exactly what you just said: "*one more the highest descriptor value*".  So, for instance, if you have just `socket1` in the `fds`, then `nfds` needs to be `socket1 + 1`.  If you have both `socket1` and `socket2` in the `fds`, then `nfds` needs to be `max(socket1, socket2) + 1`. And so on, with the more descriptors you add to the `fds`.

> Also if I've got select fds added via FD_SET(), when select returns...
>
> what's the way to iterate thru all the fds that are set (e.g. readable)

There isn't one.  At least, not a portable way.  You need to test each socket individually, eg:

```c
if ( FD_ISSET(socket1, &fds) ) {
    ...
}
if ( FD_ISSET(socket2, &fds) ) {
    ...
}
```

If you put `socket1` and `socket2` in an array/list, you can then enumerate that instead, eg:

```c
SOCKET sockets[] = ...;
int numSockets = ...;

for(int i = 0; i < numSockets; ++i) {
    if ( FD_ISSET(sockets[i], &fds) ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

> i was hoping there would be an iterator function.

There isn't one.

Comment: So the first arg should be max(socket1, socket2) + 1 and not 3 in your example. It's the highest descriptor value + 1. Correct?

Comment: @dashman "*It's the highest descriptor value + 1. Correct?*" - yes